# Setting default static value in select option

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a problem with setting a default value of `select` tag. Here is my some snippet:

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_company" name="company" formControlName="company">
    <option value="null" [selected]="true"> {{ 'khanbankCpmsApp.company.default' | translate }}</option>
    <option
        [ngValue]="companyOption.id === editForm.get('company').value?.id ? editForm.get('company').value : companyOption"
                *ngFor="let companyOption of companies;"
    >
       {{ companyOption.name }}</option>
</select>
```

When it's default by that static value should be displayed on select. But result is:

[image]

What did i do wrong ? any advice ?

[image]

Comment: Can you see what's the resulting value, by inspecting the elements via the developer tools?

Comment: @johey yes i will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a reactive form, so you need to set the FormControl into your formGroup like.

```html
<form [formGroup]="companyGroup">
    <select class="form-control"  name="company" formControlName="company">
        <option value="1"> One </option>
        <option value="2"> Two </option>
        <option value="3"> Three </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and .ts file contains the

```js
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  companyGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.companyGroup = this.fb.group({
      company : ''
    })
    this.companyGroup.get('company').patchValue('2');
  }
}
```

Demo link [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z63wtk?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: what, this is exactly same as my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a reactive form, you should set the default value in the reactive form so that the correct option gets selected by the framework.

```
editForm = this.fb.group({ 
  name: [null, [Validators.required]], 
  status: [null, [Validators.required]], 
  dueDate: [], loanAmount: [], grantsOpenUntil: [], 
  users: [], 
  company: ['khanbankCpmsApp.company.default'], 
  });
```

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_company" name="company" formControlName="company">
    <option [ngValue]="'khanbankCpmsApp.company.default'"> {{ 'khanbankCpmsApp.company.default' | translate }}</option>
    <option
        [ngValue]="companyOption.id === editForm.get('company').value?.id ? editForm.get('company').value : companyOption"
                *ngFor="let companyOption of companies;"
    >
       {{ companyOption.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: where that company gets from ?

Comment: company is your formControlName.. formControlName="company". If you use formbuilder it must be something like. fb.group({ company: [null, ...] })

Comment: ```editForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [null, [Validators.required]],
    status: [null, [Validators.required]],
    dueDate: [],
    loanAmount: [],
    grantsOpenUntil: [],
    users: [],
    company: [null],
  });
```

Comment: Okay, try new suggestion.